# Displaying dynamic list as header text in data table using JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to display the dynamic list a value as header text in data table but the value is getting repeated for each row. I need the header to be displayed only once at top and input text also only once should come in row-wise where each row has row edit and save option.This is my code.

```
<p:dataTable id="examMarksVie"
             var="internal"
             editable="true"
             rowIndexVar="rowindex"
             rowKey="#{internal.internalMarkId}"
             style="width:90%;margin-left:70px;margin-top:5%"
             value {exam.internalMarkList}">

            <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{exam.doSaveInternalMark}" update="examMarksVie"/>

            <p:column headerText="#{message['label.studentManagement.transferCertificate.studentName']}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{internal.studentDetails.studentApplicationID.firstName} #{internal.studentDetails.studentApplicationID.middleName} #{internal.studentDetails.studentApplicationID.lastName}" />
            </p:column>


 <p:column
                                        headerText="#{message['label.exam.internal.weightage']}"
                                        style="width:265px">
                                        <p:dataTable var="al" value="#{internal.interALlocMarkList}">
                                            <p:columns value="#{internal.interALlocMarkList}" var="id"
                                                columnIndexVar="index"
                                                headerText="#{internal.interALlocMarkList[index].internalAllocId.titleName} out of #{internal.interALlocMarkList[index].internalAllocId.titleName}">
                                                <p:inputText value="#{al.allocMark}" />
                                            </p:columns>
                                        </p:dataTable>
                                    </p:column>
```

[image]

Comment: Change the layout possibly using a different component like `<p:dataList>` along with `<p:dataTable>`.

Comment: So what is duplicated because only `p:column` you have posted is `studentName` and this column header is not duplicated.

Comment: @Geinmachi  i have added the code which is repeating can you find it.

Comment: Make your code an [mcve], see also http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info